# Connection shape script shows GUID not a name of reference element

Tags: enterprise-architect

In my MDG technology I have a my own type of connection "MyConn" extended of `InformationFlow`. "MyConn" has tag "ServiceRef" which is linked via tagged value to another MDG element «MyService».
When I use in "MyConn" shape script the construction

```
print(" -> ");
print("#TAG:ServiceRef#");
```

the shape depicts GUID of "MyService", not a "Name", as I experienced in other cases (for element, not connections).

Is there a way to show name of referenced element, not a GUID ? Sparx 13.5

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's obviously a(nother) bug in EA. It's still broken in 15.1. You might report that (or use your time for something more useful). Eventually post the question on Sparx' forum and one of the nice Sparxian (KP if any) will have an idea.

Since shape script is so limited the only way around would be to use an add-in call to decipher the name from the GUID, just like

```
print("#yourAddin:decipherGUID#");
```

You would need to implement that `decipherGUID` operation in your add-in. If you desperately need that be aware that for each connector to be rendered EA will call that add-in. That can easily drop performance to non-usability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are able to create an add-in, but we cannot use it in a production environment due several reason.

Comment: I know these reasons from my customer as well ;-)